# Probability of any 3 chosen numbers, appearing adjacent to each other, but in any order, in a set of numbers that is X digits in length

Tags: probability

Not sure if my title makes it clear what I'm asking so:
Say we have an ID number that is 15 digits long, any number is valid for those 15 digits, so 0-9. I'm interested in the probability that a set of numbers (say 2,4,6), will appear in this ID, adjacent to each other (246), but in any order (246, 642, 426, etc.). Multiple appearances allowed.

I've looked through a few questions, but I don't think they entirely match my use case, and frankly they're a little beyond my level of understanding. I've been told previously that 10C3 should give me an answer for (I assume) an ID that's 3 digits in length. However that gives me 120, which I'm not really sure how that works for 6 combinations (246, 264, 426, 462, 624, 642) out of 10^3. Could use an explanation on that if it is indeed correct. Anyway, I wanted to expand this to to determine the probability for (in theory) any length of digits ("15" was arbitrary, I just wanted a number that wasn't "10" so I couldn't mix it up with 0-9 giving you 10 possibilities per digit).

Ideally I'm looking for some sort of formula I can just plug things into, but I could really, really, use a good explanation of the math behind it. Ideally for someone with low mathematical comprehension.

Comment: Please clarify your statement:”in sequence, like 246, but in any order (246,642,426)”. The two parts are contradictory.

Comment: @insipidintegrator suppose you like multiples of three and are excited when you see three distinct multiples of three together.  A number like 147235 doesn't make you excited.  A number like 24**369**7 does.  A number like **639**250 also does.  A number like 1**396**39 also does (*and might even make you extra excited since that is also* 139**639** *as well as* 13**963**9)

Comment: @JMoravitz But am I supposed to be happy seeing $1\color{red}32\color{red}944\color{red}66$?

Comment: I'd assume no, they aren't together.  At least, that is my interpretation of the problem.  I interpret the OP's phrase "in sequence but in any order" to mean what we would have described as *consecutive* or *adjacent*.  Of course, the OP should be the one to clarify and confirm if that is indeed what is meant.

Comment: Ah, yes, I did mean adjacent to each other. No other digits between them. Thank you.

Comment: Are the sets to be disjoint, or can they overlap, eg would you count $24624$ as three occurrences ?

Comment: Hadn't considered that, but yes it makes sense that it should be counted as three occurrences.